# Creating Empty DF and adding column is NOT working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a empty dataframe and append new column. I tried to do this by two option. Option A is working but Option B is not working. Please help!

Option A:

`

```
var initialDF1 = Seq(("test")).toDF("M") 
initialDF1 = initialDF1.withColumn(("P"), lit(s"P"))
initialDF1.show
+----+---+
|   M|  P|
+----+---+
|test|  P|
+----+---+
```

`

Option B: (Not working)

`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val schema = StructType(List(StructField("N", StringType, true)))
var initialDF = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema)
initialDF = initialDF.withColumn(("P"), lit(s"P"))
initialDF.show
+---+---+
|  N|  P|
+---+---+
+---+---+
```

`

Comment: How is it not working? Your dataframe also has a new column when using option B.

Comment: column is added. But the values is not getting added.

Comment: where would the value come from ? you literally created an empty dataframe... If the dataframe had any rows they'd all have a P (as in your first example)

Comment: with column is a schema manipulation command and you provide a default value

Answer (score 3):

It is working as intended the withColumn command only affects the schema and it allows setting a value to existing records (lit or some other calculation) but that would only be applied to existing rows. In your second case you created an empty dataframe. the withColum iterates on that and adds a "P" to any existing row (none..)

Comment: Is there way to insert values using Option B?